# Operator '<' cannot be applied to types 'string' and 'number'

Tags: angular9

I am trying to verify that if the password is less than three, this message will appear on the interface:

```
password must be at least 5 chars long!
```

But it shows a red line at the number three,,,
How can I solve the problem?

code:

```
else if(this.user.employee.password< 3){
  this.errorMsg="password must be at least 5 chars long!";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check the length of the `password` using [`String length`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/length) property as follows.

```
else if (this.user.employee.password.length < 3){
  this.errorMsg = "password must be at least 5 chars long!";
}
```